# How to implement cursor based pagination in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, pagination, cursor

I am trying to implement a cursor based pagination server. I am using neo4j for database. I have a confusion on generating cursor for records. I understand cursor  should be unique and sequential to generate pagination properly. I think we cannot take neo4j ID as cursor. In my db I will have unique uuid for each nodes but that will not signify it is sequential. I also have db field created that could be used but that field might not be unique. What is proper way to solve this problem with ne04j?

Comment: Are you trying to make a pagination system on a cypher query result ?

Comment: yes, I just need a way to implement unique cursor for each record that is sequential.

Comment: I am thinking of generating cursor based on created+uuid field

Comment: Just adding a `SKIP` and a `LIMIT` in your query it's not sufficient ?

Comment: I do use LIMIT  to limit the no of records but when Implementing cursor based pagination we need to send in cursor with each node.

Comment: @Yalamber I think that you can to use a relationship like `:NEXT`.

Comment: @stdob can you explain a bit on relationship like :NEXT?

Comment: @Yalamber You can, at the time of the creation of nodes (records), bind them to chains by relationships that have a type corresponding to the cursor, and an identifier corresponding to a specific cursor. The same can be done on the result of the query - create the appropriate chain and return the cursor identifier. Then you can always find the following result from the cursor identifier and the node ID.

Comment: @stdob Right now How I identify/create cursor is I base64 encode uuid and created timestamp both of which are also stored properties in the node itself.